# CamembertForSequenceClassification : training is not working

Tags: bert-language-model, huggingface-transformers, huggingface-tokenizers, huggingface-datasets

I try to use and adapt a notebook based on huggingface models: ***Text Classification on GLUE*** (https://colab.research.google.com/github/huggingface/notebooks/blob/master/examples/text_classification.ipynb#scrollTo=YZbiBDuGIrId)

My goal is to classify a sentence (16 classes predefined).

So I followed the notebook and did. My data looks like below.

```
id  data     label              langue

0   text_1   label_1            Français
 
0   text_2   label_2            Français

1   text_3   label_3            Français


import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datasets import load_dataset, load_metric, DatasetDict, Features, Value, ClassLabel, Dataset
```

I have a labeldict like this

```
{'label_1': 0,
 'label_2': 1,
 ...}

dataset = load_dataset('csv', sep="|", data_files={"train" : train_paths, "test" : test_paths})
```

output:

```
DatasetDict({
    train: Dataset({
        features: ['id', 'data', 'label', 'langue'],
        num_rows: ...
    })
    test: Dataset({
        features: ['id', 'data', 'label', 'langue'],
        num_rows: ...
    })
})
```

Did all before in the notebook and when I try to do this:

```
trainer = Trainer(
    model,
    args,
    train_dataset=encoded_dataset["train"],
    eval_dataset=encoded_dataset[validation_key],
    tokenizer=tokenizer,
    compute_metrics= compute_metrics,
    callbacks=[MLflowCallback()]
)

trainer.train()
```

I have the error: `The following columns in the training set  don't have a corresponding argument in` CamembertForSequenceClassification.forward `and have been ignored: langue, id, data.` `IndexError: tuple index out of range`

What can I do ?

Comment: Please post the full error stacktrace.